# How to test client and server behaviour of a java program?

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu, port

TLDR: How to test client and server behaviour of a java program in Ubuntu? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

I wrote a Java program that tries to satisfy the following requirements.

> Rock-paper-scissors is a round-based hand game between two opponents
>   in which each opponent forms one of three shapes, e.g. rock, paper or
>   scissors at each round.
>
> Your program should run with the java RockPaperScissors
>   [<.IP_address.>] <.port_number.> command, where <.IP address.> is the
>   IP address of the host to which your program should connect and <.port
>   number.> is the port number to which the socket is bound. The first
>   command line argument, i.e., <.IP address.>, is optional. If it is not
>   given, the executed program behaves as the server. It opens a server
>   socket at port <.port number.> and listens for a connection. If it is
>   given, the executed program behaves as the client. It connects to the
>   host with IP address <.IP address.> and port <.port number.>. After
>   the connection is established, the client sends a message including
>   the shapes chosen by itself to the server.

I get the following output after I run the program with server behaviour by only giving 8080 as argument. I suspect client doesn't work because there is no "local address" to be reached, as seen below. Is the lack of IP normal? What should the client use as IP to reach the server (in the same machine)?

Any advice on solving the problem? I'm a noob at network knowledge. Here are the source codes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy8tzmsekunrmd0/_chrome.7z?dl=0 (You can test the complete program with arguments)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      28475/java
```

Comment: in the ip write "localhost"

Comment: @amirag infinite loop happens

Comment: well, you put in `do-while`. did you make sure that you can quit it? did you sent something to the server?